# Darken a background image without affecting the Text

Tags: html, css, z-index, transparent

I am almost there, but the text inside the a-tag should not be affected by the semi-transparent overlay:

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisPrefect/GPLfM/

The text should be bright white, regardless if you hover over the image or not.

I can add more html elements if necessary, but I would like to keep it to the minimum.

There is a new element added with:

```
.tint:before
```

which has a semi transparent background:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
```

But the "before" element is over the text inside the a-element too and makes it dark.

Can this be solved with z-index ordering?

Thank you!
Chris

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can easily be solved by ordering the stacking order of your elements correctly. Note the use of relative positioning on the text content.

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.block:hover:before {
  background: none;
}

.block h2,
.block p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a class="block" style="background-image:url(http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/2011-11/greece001.jpg);" href="#">
  <h2>Dogs are great sleepers</h2>
  <p>Mine can sleep all day long</p>
</a>


<a class="block" style="background-image:url(http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/2011-11/greece001.jpg);" href="#">
  <h2>Dogs are great sleepers</h2>
  <p>Mine can sleep all day long</p>
</a>
```

Comment: You can even remove `z-index` from `.tint` and `.tint:before` entirely.

Comment: Or you could just use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset;`. http://jsfiddle.net/tx58qf3m/5/

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll Using large box shadows destroys page performance, especially when scrolling on content-rich pages.

Comment: @Nit I didn't know that, do you have any reference?

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll There's countless examples, simply Google along the lines of box-shadow performance issues, see [this Airbnb](http://nerds.airbnb.com/box-shadows-are-expensive-to-paint/) article for an example.

Comment: @Nit actually that issue seems to be resolved by now https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99045

Comment: I dont understand @brouxhaha that you can remove the z-index completely. Doesnt that defeat the whole thing?

Comment: The way elements stack. The parent (`.tint`) will always be the first (or bottom) in the stack - it can never be above any children including pseudo elements. By default, `:before` will always come next and stack on top of the parent, and any children of `.tint` will come next and stack on top of both in order. Go to the fiddle and try it.

Comment: Generally, `z-index` only affects an element's stacking order in relation to its siblings, so setting it on `.tint` only affects how it gets stacked with its siblings, not its children.

Comment: I was able to implement this without the z-index.

Comment: @RonE Thanks for highlighting this, I wrote this post many years ago when I was less experienced with CSS. I've updated the example to remove redundant code.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution is to contain the contents of the link in an element and apply to background to that.

HTML:

```
<a class="tint t1 block" style="background-image:url(http://cdn.impressivewebs.com/2011-11/greece001.jpg);" href="#">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Themenwoche: Glatt gelogen!</h2>
        <p>Aktueller Beitrag</p>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="tint block" style="background-image:url(http://toxic.fm/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/topelement-255x260.jpg)" href="#">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Themenwoche: Glatt gelogen!</h2>
        <p>Aktueller Beitrag</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family:arial;
}

a {
    color:#fff;
}

.block {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
}

.tint {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay {
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.overlay *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.tint:hover .overlay {
    background: none;
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P36sw/1/).